# CakePHP table relation $belongsTo show no recors in drop down menu in add action

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I have simple ralation tables : Each table (Agrement) 'umowas' have one item from table (Adult) 'rodzics' and one item from table (Children) 'dziecis'.

When call myaddress.com/cakephp/Umowas/add i do not see drop down menu for item 'rodzic_id' and 'dzieci_id' with its items names. I see only numer.

For example drop down menu for 'rodzic_id' shows Array(1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>3), not names of its record, like array( 1=>'Item name 1', 2=> 'Item name 2').....

Debug.log and Error.log is empty.

My query at bottm of screen is:
    
    `Nr  Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)
    1   SELECT`Rodzic`.`id`FROM`akademia-uat`.`rodzics`AS`Rodzic`WHERE 1 = 1      2   2   3
    2   SELECT`Dzieci`.`id`FROM`akademia-uat`.`dziecis`AS`Dzieci`WHERE 1 = 1      1   1   2`

My code is:

```
<?php
class UmowasController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Umowas';
    var $scaffold;
    var $helpers = array('Form' );

    function index() {
        $this->Umowa->recursive = 1;
        $umowas = $this->Umowa->find('all');
        $this->set('umowas', $umowas);
}   
}
?>

-----------------------------------------

<?php

class RodzicsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Rodzics';
    var $scaffold;

function index() {
    $this->Rodzic->recursive = 1;
    $rodzics = $this->Rodzic->find('all');
    $this->set('rodzics', $rodzics);
}    
}
-------------------------------------------------------
<?php

class DziecisController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Dziecis';
    var $scaffold;

function index() {
    $this->Dzieci->recursive = 1;
    $dziecis = $this->Dzieci->find('all');
    $this->set('dziecis', $dziecis);
} 
}

------------------------------------------

<?php
    class Umowa extends AppModel { 
        var $name = 'Umowa';



    public $belongsTo = array(
    'Rodzic' => array(
        'className'     => 'Rodzic',
        'conditions'    => '',
        'order'         => '',
        'foreignKey'    => 'rodzic_id' //or your external key
    ),
    'Dzieci' => array(
        'className'     => 'Dzieci',
        'conditions'    => '',
        'order'         => '',
        'foreignKey'    => 'dzieci_id' //or your external key
    )
); 
 var $helpers = array('Form' );


 function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            $this->Umowa->create();
            $this->Umowa->save($this->data);
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
      }
        $rodzics = $this->Umowa->Rodzic->generateList();       
        $this->set('rodzics', $rodzics);
        $dziecis = $this->Umowa->Dzieci->generateList();       
        $this->set('dziecis', $dziecis);
    }
}
?>
--------------------------------------------------------

<?php

class Rodzic extends AppModel
{
        var $name = 'Rodzic';
        var $hasMany = 'Umowa';
}
?>

-------------------------------------------------------
<?php

class Dzieci extends AppModel
{
        var $name = 'Dzieci';
        var $hasMany = 'Umowa';
}
?>

---------------------------------------------------------

view/Rodzics/add and do not exists
view/Umowas/add do not exists
view/Dziecis/add do not exist

`
```

My Tables is like this:

```
`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dziecis` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imie_dziecka` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nazwisko_dziecka` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rodzics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imie_rodzica` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nazwisko_rodzica` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefon` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adres_email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ulica` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `umowas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `warunek_umowy` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_rozwiazania_warunku` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_zawarcia_umowy` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_zerwania_umowy` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `nr_umowy` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rok_szkolny` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wizerunek` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `miesiac_rozpoczecia_platnosci` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `raty` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `utworzono` date NOT NULL,
  `modyfikacja` date NOT NULL,
  `zabezpieczona` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `wydrukowana` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `dzieci_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rodzic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_umowy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `miasto_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `klasa_lub_grupa_dziecka_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cennik_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary, mixed up, improperly formatted code you are showing there. The main problem however is that it lacks the important parts, 1. the mysterious `generateList()` method, 2. the `Umowas/add` view. And please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: For a better understanding of your code, name your database tables, models and controllers in English languages​​. 

After set the Router parameters in your languages.

Comment: Sorry about that non english names, i did not know that is problem for. Next @ndm can you talk more about generateList() method? What is problem with that?

Comment: @ndm - i have done some search over google and learn about : `bash lib/Cake/Console/cake bake` and done all add/edit/delete action and all add/delete/edit.ctp files in automatic way. Anyway it did not help. Problem exist. Please help me with this, i am stuck for 48h in one point and cant go forward.

Comment: @Salines - do you think that non english names could be the problem of not working array drop down list? i have made an example code from book (Packt-Publishing-CakePHP-Application-Development) with books and authors tables and it works, it has drop down menu with authors in action add for model books.

Comment: Read this: Inflection Configuration http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#inflection-configuration

Comment: I have read that page. Is it problem with names you think?

Comment: I have translated all to english, and have turned on i18n module, forks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have translate all tables and names in project to english. Also done job with command line cake bake, and all tables started to works and display fields. Problem was in models, and not declared public $displayField.
Everyboday have to do scafolding command line tool and have english names, that a lot of easy. And most importand is to declare $displayField and point it to title, or name field in each tables.
Thanks all for support.